# How to combine two rows with the same id in an UPDATE query MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with addresses and postcodes in different rows but linked by an id column.

CURRENT STATE

`id`  `addressLabel`    `addressValue`
`22`  `home address`  `xxxxx`
`22`  `home postcode` `yyyy yyyy`

DESIRED STATE

`id` `addressLabel` `addressValue`
`22` `home address` `xxxxxx, yyyy yyy`

I want to concatenate the two rows with the same id into the addressValue column with a  comma separator (then delete the postcode). 
I have seen plenty of examples using SELECT but I can't see how they would work with UPDATE.

Comment: can you format the record values between ``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a selfjoin in the UPDATE statement:

```
update mytable a
join mytable p using(id)
set a.addressValue = concat(a.addressValue, ', ', p.addressValue)
where a.id = 22
  and a.addressLabel = 'home address'
  and p.addressLabel = 'home postcode';

delete from mytable
where id = 22
  and addressLabel = 'home postcode';
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/649ef3/1

Remove the conditions `id = 22` if you want to affect the full table.